# How to fix horizontal line at the bottom and text on top of <TD> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table with single TR tag and having two TD tags in it.
There are two horizontal lines or HR tags in each TD with some text. so I want fix the text on top of the TD and Horizontal line at the bottom for each column.

here is the sample code.

```
  <html>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left; width: 50%;">
                sdbasdbmnsadbmnasdsad
                <br />
                sdbasdbmnsadbmnasdsad
                <br />
                sdbasdbmnsadbmnasdsad
                <br />
                sdbasdbmnsadbmnasdsad
                <br />
                sdbasdbmnsadbmnasdsad
                <hr width="40%" />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left; width: 50%;">
                sdbasdbmnsadbmnasdsad
                <br />
                sdbasdbmnsadbmnasdsad
                <br />
                sdbasdbmnsadbmnasdsad
                <br />
                <hr width="40%" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a row beneath the text rows for the `hr`'s

```
<tr>
  <td>
    Text
  </td>
  <td>
    Text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <hr width="40%" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <hr width="40%" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now you can control the height of the individual rows to get any kind of spacing you want

Comment: Hm, I think this adds to much HTML structure and semantics to a single `<hr>`.

Comment: @insertusernamehere using tables in general is not typically preferred, but given that that is what OP is using, it's the best in a bad situation

Comment: A table for tabular content is a good thing. ;) But I know what you mean.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I may just be spoiled :) I have a CSS snippet for DIV-based "tables" that behave almost the same way

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the `<hr>` and simply add a border on the bottom of each `<td>`:

```
<td style="text-align: left; width: 50%; border-bottom: 1px solid red;"></td>
```

If you want to keep the `<hr>` (for example if it's not as wide as the `<td>` use this instead:

```
<hr style="display:inline-block; width:40%;">
```

Comment: Adding bottom border to each TD will merge two horizontal lines.

Comment: That's why you can use the second solution and leave your code as it is with 'display: inline-block;' on the <hr>.

Answer (score 2):

I'd get rid of the `hr` elements, and use the `border-bottom` CSS property on the `td` to render the lines on the bottom, and `vertical-align` to force the text to the top.

Comment: Adding bottom borders will merge two horizontal lines.

Comment: You might need something more extreme then; check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GnUJs/ - it uses your original markup plus absolute and relative positioning, plus a little padding on the td.